# SF book with long distance running as an element of military tactic

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for the title of the book (and name of the author), in which one of elements of a "particular military tactic" is long distance running.

All I know is that the book is originally in English and it is science-fiction. Unfortunately I can't provide any other details, as that's all they've written in the competition (sorry, book prizes are in Polish, so you won't be interested).

Comment: I don't know about long distance running as military tactic but what it comes to mind is "The Running Man" by Stephen King ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Running_Man_(novel)))
In which the main character is ex military pilot, convicted of mass murder and he is to take part in a televised game show as punishment

Comment: Yes, it's quite similar thing. Unfortunately too far from the description for the competition purposes. But I didn't know there was a book - I've seen only the movie.

Comment: It's fantasy, rather than SF, so perhaps not what you're looking for, but Brandon Sanderson's [The Way of Kings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Way_of_Kings) features "bridge runners" who run for long distances carrying bridges so that the main army can move about. It's the only book I've read that remotely fits your description though so I figured I'd mention it.

Comment: The book definitely had to be SF, but the overall idea of bridge runners is interesting, thanks. :)

Comment: For a presence of (varying) military training, one can remember **Starship Troopers**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are seeking the book "The Tactics of Mistake" by Gordon R. Dickson.  The advanced military tactics to which you are referring is the following combined with the exotic science of ontogenetics which allows the protagonist to heal his crippled knee and go on to perform significant military wins using much smaller forces.

The heart of his military strategy, based in part on fencing, is what he labels the "tactics of mistake," enticing one's opponent into overreaching, and being ready to take advantage of the mistake. This description is an adaptation of a similar concept in the novel Scaramouche by Rafael Sabatini when the character Moreau studies at the salon of the Master of Arms.

[Wiki Book Description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactics_of_Mistake)

Comment: Hmm, sounds like a good guess, thanks! I've checked if it was released in Poland (another rule of the competition, but because of the language, this one is much easier to check by myself) and it's OK. Unfortunately I couldn't find any descriptions of this novel that included the running. Can you explain in what way running is used in this tactics? This way if we have here another answer, I'll be able to chose the one that suits better.

Comment: OK, I've went through the pages and found it. Sounds great, I'll go for it, thanks! :)

Comment: I'm very happy to write that your answer was correct! Together with the answer to the second question (about Lem's "Magellanic Cloud"), it was enough to win the competition. Thanks once again! :)